# RxJS 6 / When does tap operator emit a value

Tags: rxjs, ngrx, rxjs5, rxjs6, ngrx-store

I've been wondering if it's safe to assume that after the using the tap operator, the side effect inside it has completed.

My use case is with ngrx.

```js
 ...
tap(() => {
    this.store.dispatch(new SetValue("Hello World"));
  }
}),
switchMap(() => this.store),
select(state => state.value),
tap(state => {
  if (state === undefined) {
    throw new Error("Couldn't find value");
  }
})
```

SetValue is an class that implements ngrx

```js
export class SetValue implements Action {
  readonly type = SET_VALUE;
  constructor(public payload: string) {}
}
```

What I'm trying to implement is to set a value on the store and then check if it's effectively been set.

Can I assume the dispatch has completed after tap operator?

**Answer**

I used this on *Angular Router guards* to set initial state by the parameters on the url, so I ended up filtering to only continue when the store has new value

```js
 ...
tap(() => this.store.dispatch(new SetValue("Hello World"))),
switchMap(() => this.store),
select(state => state.value),
filter(value => value === "Hello World"),
take(1)
```

Comment: I was thinking about my code too imperativly, my suggestion to any one encoutering this, is to encourage reactive programming, thinking about steams and when it sends data

Answer (score 3):

Most operations in RxJS are synchronous so if `this.store.dispatch(new SetValue("Hello World"))` won't do any async task it probably will work as expected (it's still just a Subject under the hood).

However, you shouldn't rely on this behavior. NgRx might change it's internals and in general it's better not to rely on synchronicity/asynchronicity of RxJS operators (this has already happened in the past in eg. `from()` from RxJS 4 to RxJS 5).

If you want to make sure something has been set then change your `new SetValue("Hello World")` effect to emit another action after it's done doing what it needs to do.

Comment: SetValue is a class that implements action from ngrx, how does your suggestion fit in?
`export class SetValue implements Action {
  readonly type = SET_VALUE;
  constructor(public payload: string) {}
}`

Comment: You probably handle this action in another effect because I guess you don't create an action that does nothing. So when it's done handling `SetValue` action you map it to another action telling you that `SetValue`  has finished.

Comment: I'm editing the question to a the real world problem. I'm trying to provide values on store with a RouteGuard based on the url. That is where the action dispatch. I'd like to check that values have been succesfully filled in the store, otherwise redirect to another page

Comment: Adding to what @martin said,  the ngrx also recommends us to same. Have Success/Fail action emitted based on the Load/Set Action. Then you can listen to loaded/error  states updated by Success/Fail action and decide on navigating away.

Comment: Just for completness, I ended up filtering (rxjs filter operator) next to tap, assuring the store changed the value.

Answer (score 0):

`tap` operator takes 3 arguments.

1- if the source observable emits a value, the first argument of the `tap` operator is a function that receives that emitted value as an argument.

2- if the source observable goes into an error state, the second argument of the `tap` operator is a function that receives that error as an argument. So inside here you can dispatch the error.

3- The third argument is a function that will be invoked any time the observable is marked as complete.

```
tap(observer, error, complete):Observable
```